# Gstreamer filesink works on commandline but not Java code

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, java-gstreamer

I'm trying to stream audio from a Raspberry Pi to a VM.

The Raspberry Pi has a microphone plugged into it and its pipeline is like 
so (IP/hostname info redacted):

`gst-launch-1.0 -ev alsasrc device=plughw:1,0 ! audioconvert ! rtpL24pay ! udpsink host=xxxxx port=xxxx`

The VM is running this pipeline:

`gst-launch-1.0 -ev udpsrc port=xxxx caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)44100, encoding-name=(string)L24, encoding-params=(string)2, channels=(int)2, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)636287891, timestamp-offset=(uint)692362821, seqnum-offset=(uint)11479" ! rtpL24depay ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! wavenc ! filesink location=test.wav`

Running this via command line works just fine when I end it with Ctrl+C 
(coupled with the -e switch), and the file is readable. What I'd like to do, 
however, is keep the pipeline running on the Raspberry pi via command line, 
but use a Java application for the VM's pipeline. This Java application is 
hooked to REST endpoints "/start" and "/stop". "/start" starts the pipeline 
and "/stop" *should* stop the pipeline and write to file, but when hit the "/stop" endpoint the file is of size zero and is unreadable. My code is at the bottom of this post. Any ideas on improving  the pipeline or how to make the file readable would be great. My initial  thinking was that it has to do with how I'm sending an EOS message, but not too sure. Thank you!

EDIT: Also forgot to mention that I'm running this JAR file in a Docker container, so it may have to do with ports, but again--not sure.

```java
package service.rest.controllers;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.freedesktop.gstreamer.*;
import org.freedesktop.gstreamer.event.EOSEvent;
import org.freedesktop.gstreamer.message.EOSMessage;
import org.freedesktop.gstreamer.message.Message;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import service.config.ClientSettings;
import service.config.FileSettings;
import service.postgres.Database;
import service.postgres.ExecuteDatabase;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

//pipeline running on pi@raspberrypi:
//gst-launch-1.0 -ev alsasrc device=plughw:1,0 ! audioconvert ! rtpL24pay ! udpsink host=xxxxx port=xxxx
@RestController
public class AudioCaptureController {

    @Autowired
    public Database database;

    @Autowired
    ExecuteDatabase db_executor;

    @Autowired
    ClientSettings clientSettings;

    @Autowired
    FileSettings fileSettings;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(AudioCaptureController.class.getName());
    private static final String startTemplate = "Pipeline started at %s.";
    private static final String stopTemplate = "File recorded for time window %s to %s.";
    private static final SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    private Pipeline pipe;
    private Date startTime;
    private int port;
    private int defaultLength;
    private int defaultRecordingDuration;
    private String defaultDirectory;

    public AudioCaptureController() {
    }

    /**
     * Initializes GStreamer pipeline.
     * udpsrc ! rtpL24depay ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! wavenc ! filesink
     */
    public void init() {
        port = clientSettings.getUdp_port();
        defaultLength = fileSettings.getDefault_length();
        defaultRecordingDuration = fileSettings.getDefault_recording_duration();
        defaultDirectory = fileSettings.getDefault_directory();

        Gst.init("Receiver");

        //CREATE ELEMENTS
        Element source = ElementFactory.make("udpsrc", "source");
        Element depayloader = ElementFactory.make("rtpL24depay", "depayloader");
        Element decoder = ElementFactory.make("decodebin", "decoder");
        Element converter = ElementFactory.make("audioconvert", "converter");
        Element encoder = ElementFactory.make("wavenc", "encoder");
        Element sink = ElementFactory.make("filesink", "sink");

        //CONFIGURE ELEMENTS
        Caps caps = Caps.fromString("application/x-rtp, " +
                "media=(string)audio, " +
                "clock-rate=(int)44100, " +
                "encoding-name=(string)L24, " +
                "encoding-params=(string)2, " +
                "channels=(int)2, " +
                "payload=(int)96, " +
                "ssrc=(uint)636287891, " +
                "timestamp-offset=(uint)692362821, " +
                "seqnum-offset=(uint)11479");
        source.set("port", port);
        source.setCaps(caps);

        //GENERATE WAV FILE - **Currently generating only one file**
        //todo: need a way to save specific file names. probably have to pause and restart the stream each time.
        //consider splitting the file post-processing
        //can't use multifilesink or splitmuxsink b/c no native support for wav
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662392/gstreamer-multifilesink-wav-files-splitting
        sink.set("location", defaultDirectory + "test.wav");
//        sink.set("location", "test.wav");

        //SET UP PIPELINE
        pipe = new Pipeline();
        pipe.addMany(source, depayloader, decoder, converter, encoder, sink);

        //LINK PADS
        source.link(depayloader);
        depayloader.link(decoder);
        decoder.link(converter);
        converter.link(encoder);
        encoder.link(sink);

        //HANDLE EOS/ERROR/WARNING ON THE BUS
        Bus bus = pipe.getBus();
        bus.connect((Bus.EOS) gstObject -> System.out.println("EOS " + gstObject));
        bus.connect((Bus.ERROR) (gstObject, i, s) -> System.out.println("ERROR " + i + " " + s + " " + gstObject));
        bus.connect((Bus.WARNING) (gstObject, i, s) -> System.out.println("WARN " + i + " " + s + " " + gstObject));
        bus.connect((Bus.EOS) obj -> {
            pipe.stop();
            Gst.deinit();
            Gst.quit();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Starts the GStreamer pipeline.
     */
    @RequestMapping("/start")
    public String startRecording() {
        //START PIPELINE
        pipe.play();

        startTime = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

        LOGGER.info(String.format(startTemplate, ft.format(startTime)));
        return String.format(startTemplate, ft.format(startTime));
    }

    /**
     * Stops the GStreamer pipeline and pushes the file to database.
     */
    @RequestMapping("/stop")
    public String stopRecording() {
//        if (pipe.isPlaying()) { //might have to comment this out
//            pipe.stop();
            pipe.getBus().post(new EOSMessage(pipe.getS));

//            Gst.quit();

            Date endTime = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
            String filePath = defaultDirectory + "test.wav";
            db_executor.insertRecord(database.getConnection(), ft.format(startTime), ft.format(endTime), filePath);

            LOGGER.info(String.format(stopTemplate, ft.format(startTime), ft.format(endTime)));
            return String.format(stopTemplate, ft.format(startTime), ft.format(endTime));
//        } else {
//            LOGGER.info("Pipeline is already at state " + pipe.getState());
//            return "Pipeline is already at state " + pipe.getState();
//        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Decodebin has dynamic source pads and you need to link them as they show up (they don't exist before the stream starts, as decodebin has no way to know what it is about to handle and how many pads it would need).

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/basics/pads.html?gi-language=c

For your case, it is likely that you won't need it as you don't need decoding, just the rtp depayloader. In case you want to keep it, make sure to register a `pad-added` callback and you will get the pad once it is created. At the callback you should link it to the rest of your pipeline (you can even create the rest at that point, if you'd like).